# Missing new invites at Careers

Tags: support, jobs

The [FAQ](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/invitations/162509) at Careers states:

> Are the people that you invite awesome? Well, then we’ll give you new invites for each person who creates a profile with a completeness score of at least 100.

Well, I have invited several people who have created a profile with a higher score than 100 and I am not receiving any new invites.

EDIT:

**Edit: Aparently the problem was that invitations are only issued once a week, but a week has passed and I still didn't get back any invitations.**

Answer (score 4):

> Well, I have invited several people who have created a profile with a higher score than 100 and I am not receiving any new invites.

Looking at your account, this isn't true. There's only one person you've invited with a completeness of at least 100.

#### When we don't automatically grant invites:

- We don't grant you invites more than once a week.
- We don't grant invites if you'd receive only 1. (Kinda lame to be all "HEY here's your ONE!1! invite. Don't spend it all in one place.")
- We don't grant invites during New York's nights and weekends.

You're tripping bullet point number 2 there, we'd only grant you one invite, so we don't grant it yet.

**Consolation Prize**: I've gone ahead and granted you 5 invites as a thank you for helping to test our invite system. Everything's working as intended.

Comment: Well, I am basing that statement on what I've been told by the contacts I invited. I obviously didn't have the privileges to examine it myself. Additionally, regardless of whether one or more did get to the target score, the FAQ doesn't mention there is a granting interval (one week). Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: A week has passed and I still don't have any extra invitations ...

Comment: @fons: I added some more information.